# How can I display error icon in cell of datagridview

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working with DataGridView.
I need to display error icon in each cell of datagridview, if the cell is empty.
The cells are validated on Button Click and error icon need to be displayed.

can anyone please share some ideas regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CellPainting event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) to do custom visuals on cells. It's a lot of work just to add an icon to one column, but [MSDN provides a lot of example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz(v=vs.110).aspx) you can steal and modify to suit your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the error text and icon to notify the user when they type the incorrect value into a cell. By default, when setting the ErrorText property, the error icon will not appear if the cell is in edit mode.

The following sample demonstrates how you can set a cell’s padding in the CellValidating event to provide spacing for the error icon. Since padding by default affects the location of the error icon the sample uses the CellPainting to move the position of the icon for painting.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Public Class Form1

    Inherits Form

    Private cellInError As New Point(-2, -2)

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3

        Me.DataGridView1.RowCount = 10

    End Sub

 

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then

            If e.FormattedValue.ToString() = "TEST" Then

                Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

                cell.ErrorText = "Invalid data entered in cell"

                If cell.Tag Is Nothing Then

                    cell.Tag = cell.Style.Padding

                    cell.Style.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 18, 0)

                    cellInError = New Point(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

                End If

                e.Cancel = True

            End If

        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit

        If DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).ErrorText <> String.Empty Then

            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

            cell.ErrorText = String.Empty

            cellInError = New Point(-2, -2)

            cell.Style.Padding = DirectCast(cell.Tag, Padding)

        End If

    End Sub

 
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting

        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText) Then

            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not (DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon))

            Dim container As GraphicsContainer = e.Graphics.BeginContainer()

            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(18, 0)

            e.Paint(Me.ClientRectangle, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon)

            e.Graphics.EndContainer(container)

            e.Handled = True

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```